# A generic error occurred in GDI+. ASP.NET CORE MVC using Sysytem.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I tried to save an image in ASP.NET Core MVC using System.Drawing.Image, but I got this error `A generic error occurred in GDI+`, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

I got the error in this line of code:
`newImg.Save(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, img.RawFormat);` which is in the method `SaveToFolder`.

Here is all of the code in my IRepository:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Compression;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Mime;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using AstroPhotoWebSite_v3.Data;
    using AstroPhotoWebSite_v3.Interfaces;
    using AstroPhotoWebSite_v3.Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;


    namespace AstroPhotoWebSite_v3.Repositories
    {
        public class GalaxysRepository : IRepository<GalaxysModel>
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
            private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
            private ApplicationDbContext context;

            public GalaxysRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
            {
                this.context = _context;
                _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            }

            public List<GalaxysModel> Entities => _context.Galaxys.ToList();

            private Size NewImageSize(Size imageSize, Size newSize)
            {
                Size finalSize;
                double tempval;
                if (imageSize.Height > newSize.Height || imageSize.Width > newSize.Width)
                {
                    if (imageSize.Height > imageSize.Width)
                    {
                        tempval = newSize.Height / (imageSize.Height * 1.0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempval = newSize.Width / (imageSize.Width * 1.0);
                    }
                    finalSize = new Size((int)(tempval * imageSize.Width), (int)(tempval * imageSize.Height));
                }
                else
                {
                    finalSize = imageSize;
                }
                return finalSize;
            }


            private void SaveToFolder(Image img, string fileName, string extension, Size newSize, string pathToSave)
            {
                Size imgSize = NewImageSize(img.Size, newSize);

                using (Image newImg = new Bitmap(img, imgSize.Width, imgSize.Height))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath = pathToSave;                                                               
       newImg.Save(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,img.RawFormat); //error is here: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            public async Task<GalaxysModel> Create(GalaxysModel galaxys, List<IFormFile> files)
            {
                var galaxyModel = new GalaxysModel();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Length == 0) continue;
                    galaxyModel.Decription = galaxys.Decription;
                    galaxyModel.Name = galaxys.Name;
                    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();

                    using (var img = Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream()))
                    {
                        galaxyModel.ImagePath = string.Format("/ImageFromGallery/GalaxysFull/{0}{1}", fileName, extension);
                        galaxyModel.ThumbPath = string.Format("/ImageFromGallery/GalaxysThumbs/{0}{1}", fileName, extension);

                        SaveToFolder(img, fileName, extension, new Size(1680, 1050), galaxyModel.ImagePath);
                        SaveToFolder(img, fileName, extension, new Size(450, 450), galaxyModel.ThumbPath);
                    }
                }
                galaxys.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                await _context.Galaxys.AddAsync(galaxys);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return galaxys;
            }

            public GalaxysModel GetEntity(Guid id)
            {
                return _context.Galaxys.Find(id);
            }

            public async Task<GalaxysModel> Update(GalaxysModel isoteric)
            {
                isoteric.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Galaxys.Update(isoteric);
                _context.Galaxys.OrderBy(p => p.CreatedOn);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return isoteric;
            }

            public async Task<GalaxysModel> Delete(GalaxysModel isoteric)
            {
                _context.Galaxys.Remove(isoteric);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return isoteric;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am a bit worried about a potential race condition re: your setting of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.contentrootpath?view=aspnetcore-2.2 . Why do you feel like you need to set that property?

Comment: When the exception occurs, please log the **exact** value of `_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` and share it with us. Also `img.RawFormat`.

Comment: _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath = "/ImageFromGallery/GalaxysFull/821ee675-5432-4031-9a99-ef779131f509.png"

Comment: img.RawFormat = {[ImageFormat: b96b3caf-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall I have faced the same issue, it usually happens when the folder you're trying to save the images in doesn't exist in the physical path, therefore try to create the folder and try again or you have to create the folder if it doesn't exist using the following code:

```
        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        string folderName = @"YourFolderPath";
        string path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, folderName);
        bool exists = Directory.Exists(path);
        if (!exists)                   
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        image.Save(path);
        image.Dispose();
        stream.Dispose();
```

I would suggest to use it in your SaveToFolder Function however, as I can see you have already added the folder path in the image path, you should either pass it along with the function or make this check in the create function.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the answer, I will try this, but I already have in my project folder "ImageFromGallery" .

Comment: Try going into debug mode and check the variable "pathToSave" in the SaveToFolder function it could save time to figure out the problem but I can assure you this error always happened to me when either the folder doesn't exist or you cannot access it due to some windows permission mostly when it is on secured servers.

Comment: And it is ASP.NET CORE. I can`t use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Comment: pathToSave  value is   /ImageFromGallery/GalaxysFull/d116f175-53bc-489c-8e2f-34de5067da53.png

Comment: Okay I've updated my answer a little bit to fit with ASP.Net Core, however you are missing currently the server path I think you should rewrite this code:
_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath = pathToSave;  to 
var path = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + pathToSave;
newImg.Save(path);

Comment: Thank you. I will try this now. And say you a result :)

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you so much!!! I working now this:  var path = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + pathToSave;    newImg.Save(path);